# Get ID from database onClick ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-studio, android-database

I'm using SQLite in my app. I have a listView which is populated with values from the database.

When I click on an item from the listview, I go to another page, and I would like ( with an intent), to transfer the ID FROM THE DATABASE. The problem is that I'm only transfering the ID from the position of my listView, which is wrong. For example, let's say I have :

ID      Name
1       David
2       Joseph

My listView will display both names. But if I delete David, the ID i'm getting when i click in Joseph is 1 and not 2 . And that's the problem !

So : **I want to retrieve the ID from my database and not from my listView when I click on an item**

Here's my method in my helper : UPDATED !

```
   public Cursor getAllCours()
{
    String Query = ("select ID as _id, nom from " + TABLE_COURS);
    Open();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
       return cursor;
}
```

And how I display it in my Activity :

```
  Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getAllCours();
    String[] from = { "nom" }; int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to, 0);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And finally, my listviewClickListener :

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            //I THINK THE ERROR IS HERE !
            long itemid= lv.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
            int id= (int)itemid;
            String a =lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Intent b = new Intent(AffichageCours.this,AffichageNotes.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("nom_cours",a);
            args.putInt("id",id);
            b.putExtras(args);
            startActivity(b);
        }

    });
}
```

My TABLE_COURS columns:

```
 private static final String TABLE_COURS = "cours";
private static final String COLONNE_IDCOURS = "ID";
private static final String COLONNE_COURS = "nom";

 private static final String CREATE_COURS ="CREATE TABLE cours " +
        "("+COLONNE_IDCOURS+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
        +COLONNE_COURS+" TEXT NOT NULL)";
```

How i delete with my Context Menu :

```
 @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.supprimer:
            dbhelper.deleteCours(lv.getItemAtPosition(info.position).toString());
            adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(info.position)); //the error is here..
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
```

Thank you guys !

Comment: you dont need `getItemIdAtPosition`: see the last parameter passed to `onItemClick` method, of course you need to use a right adapter that supports your db IDs like `SimpleCursorAdapter`, not `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Ok, but how do I do it using a SimpleCursorAdapter ?

Comment: as simple as this: https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/, it uses `this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);`, you would simply call `lv.setAdapter(...);` instead

Comment: Don't you have an example for my problem ? Like the code ? It's a bit complicated the link you sent me..

Comment: you have 6 lines of code, what is unclear in those? what columns do you have in TABLE_COURS?

Comment: Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select ID as _id, Name from " + TABLE_COURS, null);
        String[] from = { "Name" };
        int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to, 0);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: err, replace `Name` with `nom` since this is the name of a column in your db

Comment: And where do I write that code  ? What does android.R.id.text1 means ?

Comment: no, this is the code you should add in your activity, so remove `getAllCours` method and the whole code in your activity replace with those 5 lines of the code i sent you

Comment: I can't even do the rawQuery...

Comment: why cant you? whats wrong with rawQuery?

Comment: it doesn't recognize rawQuery.. do i need to extend my class or something ?

Comment: I think the problem is because I'm not writting that code in my databasehelper, so it does not recognize raeQuery or table_cours as well...

Comment: Yes but that code is in my DatabaseHelper whcich extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: so add `Cursor getAllCours()` method in your helper and just return the `Cursor`

Comment: And I write the code you sent me ?

Comment: and instead of `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select ID as _id, Name from " + TABLE_COURS, null);` call `Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getAllCours();`

Comment: Do i have to change something in my method of my DatabaseHelper ?

Comment: Ii'm gettint an error here (incompatible types)  **Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getAllCours();**
        String[] from = { "nom" }; int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to, 0); 
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            registerForContextMenu(lv);

Comment: you have to add `Cursor getAllCours()` method returning just the `Cursor`, not `List`, simply return `db.rawQuery("select ID as _id, nom from " + TABLE_COURS, null)`

Comment: check my code please, i updated it. Iis it correct like that ? And my listViewClickListener, I have to change it as well, don't I ?

Comment: in `getAllCours` remove everything related to `coursListe` (all you need is just `Cursor`, nothing more) and in `onItemClick` method see now the last parameter

Comment: the last parameter you mean long l ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Comment: Ok, but how do i get it , with which method i get the ID ?

Comment: the last parameter is an ID, that last parameter passed to `onItemClick` method

Comment: yes, but how do I get it from my listView ?

Comment: did you try to `Log.d` the last parameter? `Log.d("SOME_TAG", "onItemClick id: " + l);`

Comment: Yes, it gives me the ID, but now I'm not able to delete a row from my ListView. I'll edit my question and post the code of my ContextMenu

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are asking for the Id of the row in the ListView not the actual data that row is holding up. In the `onItemClick` method change this:

```
long itemid= lv.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
```

For this:

```
String courId = adapter.getItem(i);
```

The key here is to try to get the data from the `ArrayAdapter` not directly from the `ListView`.

Comment: `"not directly from the ListView"` what do you mean? what is data taken from the `ListView`?

Comment: How does the ListView has notion of the ID that you want? What is exactly the data you are putting in the ArrayAdapter?

Comment: My listView contains the collumn NAME. But when I click i want to pass the collumn ID from the name chosen. But ID FROM DATABASE

Comment: If you are not passing the ID to the ListView or the adapter in any way there's no way to obtain such ID unless you somehow sync the data by position between what you show in the list and the in memory array/list of data.

I recommend you to follow the approach by @M. Ashish. Dump your sql data into POJOs, create a custom adapter to show the data and get the original data by querying the adapter as I say in the answer.

Comment: `"there's no way to obtain such ID"`, and this is why OP should use `CursorAdapter`, the docs say: *"The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work"*, this `_id` column is used in `long CursorAdapter#getItemId(int position)` method implementation - see his edited code and how simple it is right now by just using `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

You should have use Java Objects so it will be easy for you.

Suppost you have stored Contacts in dataBase(contains fields: Name, Mobile and Address). So create a POJO for that:

```
class Contacts{
    private String name;
    private String mobile;
    private String address;

    //write getters and setters
}
```

Then, whenever you are accessing database fetch all contacts you want to show and store in `ArrayList<Contacts> mContactList;`

And then pass this list in your ListView's adapter to show data in listView.

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(context, layoutResource, mContactList);
```

Then you can retrieve the object on clicking a particular list item on the basis of position;

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           Contacts contact = mContactList.get(i);
           // now you can do whatever you want;
        }

    });
```

Comment: `"You should have use Java Objects"`, no, OP's data model is a `Cursor`, so he should use some kind of `CursorAdapter`, not `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Yes, he can also do that, But main point is accessing database frequently for small things is not a good idea.

Comment: this is what sqlitedb is for, there is no need to replicate its data in ram

Comment: `CursorAdapter` is deprecated and not recommended for usage by Google. I agree with the approach suggested by @M.Ashish.

Comment: @mikehc `"CursorAdapter is deprecated and not recommended for usage by Google "`, since when? do you mean that one `CursorAdapter` constructor which is deprecated (but two others are recommended)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using a custom adapter, why dont you try this inside onItemClickListener

```
String idThatYouWant = listeCours.get(i).getId();
```